# Writer's fingers begin to meld with a typewriter/computer

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think it's a golden age story or short novel, but a man is using a typewriter or computer, some sort of writing machine, and his fingers begin to fuse to the machine. He can pull his fingers away, and they stretch, but he cannot remove them.

May have ended in a sort of symbiotic relationship.

Anyone have any idea of the title/author? This is seriously bugging me!

Your help is appreciated!